# Exhibit the complete table of multiplication for $(\mathbb{Z} / 15 \mathbb{Z})^*$, and use this to solve $7X \equiv 3 \pmod{15}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have no idea how to start this question? I know how to build a multiplication table for $(\mathbb{Z} / 15 \mathbb{Z})$, but not for $(\mathbb{Z} / 15 \mathbb{Z})^*$? Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you know what the elements of $(\mathbb{Z} / 15 \mathbb{Z})^{*}$ are?

Comment: No, I don't know the elements.

Comment: The elements of $(\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})^{*}$ are the units of $(\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$, which in this case are the elements that are coprime to $n$. There should be 8 here.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, use that the group of units functor respects products, so that we get $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_4$.  That is we exploit the fact that $\Bbb Z_{15}\cong\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_5$.  It should be fairly routine (if not a little tedious, since it will contain $64$ entries) to write out the table.

For the second part, note that $-2$ is the multiplicative inverse to $7\bmod15$, since indeed $-2\cdot7+1\cdot15=1$.  Thus we get $x\equiv-6\equiv9\bmod15$.

Comment: Can you explain the first part a bit more? How do obtain the elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/ 15 \mathbb{Z})^∗$?

Comment: Sure.  By CRT (the Chinese remainder theorem), we have $\Bbb Z_{15}\cong\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_5$.  But for any prime $p$, we have $\Bbb Z_p^*\cong\Bbb Z_{p-1}$.  Thus the result.  I left out a detail or two.

Answer (score 0):

Use the extended Euclidean algorithm, which has only one step:

$15 = 2\cdot 7 + 1$.

Then $1 = 1\cdot 15 + (-2)\cdot 7$ and so $(-2)\cdot 7 \equiv 1\mod 15$ or $(-2)\cdot 7 =1$ in $\Bbb Z_{15}$.

Thus multiplying $7x=3$ with $-2$ gives $x=-6$ or $x= 9$ in $\Bbb Z_{15}$